# how do you do a mysql WHERE something = 'something' OR ... (PHP)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Is it possible to do an OR statement like this?

```
WHERE pR.projectRelationId = '$id[ 0 ]' OR '$id[ 1 ]' OR '$id[ 2 ]'
AND pR.type = 'yada' AND
```

or do you have to keep redeclaring the comparison:

```
        WHERE 
            pR.projectRelationId = '$id[ 0 ]' OR 
            pR.projectRelationId = '$id[ 1 ]' OR 
            pR.projectRelationId = '$id[ 2 ]'
            AND
            pR.type = 'yada' AND
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
pR.projectRelationId IN ('$id[ 0 ]', '$id[ 1 ]', '$id[ 2 ]')
```

Comment: ahhhhhh... COOL! I'll give it a try.. hangon!

Answer (score 0):

Use with `IN`

```
WHERE pR.projectRelationId IN ('$id[ 0 ]','$id[ 1 ]','$id[ 2 ]') AND pR.type = 'yada' AND
```